# C# Call Method On Return

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a multithreaded C# application in which a button press (`Button homeBut`) begins a new thread which executes a given method.  On click, I disable the button and start the thread.

To re-enable the button, I currently do this at the end of the method:

```
if (InvokeRequired)//if accessing from different thread
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action<Button>(enableButton), new object[] { homeBut });
    }
```

There are multiple places from which the method could return and I was hoping to avoid copying and pasting this code snippet into 4 different places to ensure the button is always re-enabled.

Is there a way that I can execute such a code block whenever the method returns so that I am only writing it once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was hoping to avoid copying and pasting this code snippet into 4 different places to ensure the button is always re-enabled.

Well, how about a method, that's usually what they are for.

```
void EnableHomeButton()
{
    if (InvokeRequired)//if accessing from different thread
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action<Button>(enableButton), new object[] { homeBut });
    }
    else
    {
        enableButton(homeBut);
    }
}
```

Also avoid creating your own threads. Start [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
DisableButton();
Task.Factory.StartNew(DoWhatEver).ContinueWith(EnableHomeButton);
```

Comment: Thanks weston; the ContinueWith method is exactly what I was looking for.  Is there any disadvantage to using a task instead of a thread?

Comment: No because a task runs on one of number of background threads from a thread pool, but as these are threads that get reused and you don't have to create them so it's faster. (Starting a thread is a fairly expensive thing to do).

Answer (score 2):

Here are three ways:

1. Create an object that does whatever you need to do when it goes out of scope (for example, with the [using pattern](http://www.dotnetperls.com/using)).
2. Change the function to only have a single return path.
3. Call the function from an outer function that does whatever you need to do after the function returns.
4. Use `try`/`finally`.

Comment: destructor? What do you mean here?

Comment: In this case, 2 is not really a good option.  I was hoping to avoid Option 3.  Can you elaborate on Option 1?

Comment: Well I hope he doesn't mean actual destructors http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/66x5fx1b.aspx don't attempt to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution you might consider is this:

```
private async void SomeButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DisableButton();
        await ALongRunningTaskAsync();
    }
    finally
    {         
        EnableButton();
    }
}
```

By using async/await you know the program will switch back to the original thread, in this case the UI thread, and even try-finally will work. Just make sure the `ALongRunningTaskAsync` returns a Task (or Task)

Answer (score 0):

I am not much clear that how you are invoking a thread. Kindly specify.
If a function/thread is being Invoked using BeginInvoke then you can specify the "async callback" method which will be triggered at the end of the thread.

Following is the working example of code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Del del = new Del(Notify);
        del.BeginInvoke("abc", callback, new object { });
    }

    private static void callback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
       if (InvokeRequired)//if accessing from different thread
       {
        this.Invoke(new Action<Button>(enableButton), new object[] { homeBut });
       }
       Console.Write("Callback Triggerd. Thread Completed");
    }
    // Declare a delegate. 
    delegate void Del(string str);

    // Declare a method with the same signature as the delegate. 
    static void Notify(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Notification received for: {0}", name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I use a button_clicked event to first disable the button: `homeBut.Enabled = false`.  Then I start a new thread targeted at a method: `Thread thr = new Thread(homeAxes)`.  When `homeAxes()` returns, I need to re-enable the button.

Comment: @Derek, Is There a possibility that you can use Delegate then your callback can be handled easily as described above